# JMeter - How to put a variable in Parameter Values for Prepared Select

Tags: jdbc, parameters, jmeter, prepared-statement

I read https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-initialize-database-variables-and-assign-them-values-for-multiple-thread-groups

But I want to know if I can set the "Parameter values" value in the JDBC Prepared Select using the following technique, involving Set Variable or User Variables.

You can see that when I try this, I get the errors below.

Note: The following did work:
[image]

[image: 2]

Comment: Do you mean `${__V(consumer_id_${count})}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) would be:

```
${__V(consumer_id_${counter})}
```

If you're uncertain with the proper syntax go for the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: I'll add another thing I forgot: the `counter` in my for-each controller was supposed to export the variable name `counter`..